# Why is yandex.ru able to determine my location?

Tags: anonymity

Yandex.ru correctly shows the location of my provider ukrtelecom's pool - Kiev. I use Tor in high security mode.

Nothing helps - I tried Tor and VPNs.

Only yandex does this. There are no cookies inside Tor and Firefox.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you running Tor? Please visit check.torproject.org and check that you have configured it right. Translation to our Russian Tor user: Ты уверен что ты используешь Тор правильно? Посити check.torproject.org и проверь свои настройки.

Comment: I have checked: "Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor."

Comment: Yandex determines my location also when I use Securitykiss VPN and ZenMate VPN. I have not found any way to hide from Yandex.

Comment: There is a icon of a lock in top left corner. Press it and goto permissions. Block the "access your location" permission.

Comment: I am sorry to write here in Answer section. I registered incorrectly and stackexchange cut me off my question, so that I can not comment without 50 reputation. Comment to NeverMine: the lock icon shows "you have granted no special permissions to this site".
I have checked about:config and see that geo.enabled is set to false

Comment: You haven't logged in whilst using Tor, have you?

Comment: @FynnMazurkiewicz have said the right thing. Please check if you logged in or not.